# iOS Crash CoreFoundation CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crashlytics

I've got this issue being reported via Crashlytics, although I've been unable to replicate it locally.

How I can catch this crash and fix it?

[[image]][]